# Using Subform with computed fields in XPage on Domino 9.x server

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, subform, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a Notes Form (Personnel) that contains a Notes Subform (that I call DocInfo) which has computed fields for storing original author and created date.

Created field formula

```
@If(@IsAvailable(CreatedOrig); CreatedOrig; @Text(@Created) + " by " + @Text(@Author))
```

Author field formula

```
@UserName
```

I have an XPage with a document source of "Personnel" and `computeWithForm` set to `both`. On a Domino 8.5.3 server the XPage computes and saves the Created and Author field on the back end Note. However, on a Domino 9.0.1 server the XPage does not compute the fields and the fields don't appear in the Document Properties of the back end Note.

```
 <xp:dominoDocument 
    var="document1" 
    formName="Personnel"
    computeWithForm="both">
        <xp:this.parentId>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.get("PID")}]]>
        </xp:this.parentId>
 </xp:dominoDocument>
```

I am guessing that somehow the Domino 9.0.1 server engine does not include the subform fields in the `computeWithForm` function? This has worked on our 8.5.3 servers for a couple years, but does not work now on a 9.0.1 server?

Any help, suggestions or information would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what the exact problem in your case, but I have experienced some weird problems before, with computed fields and computeWithForm on XPages. There is no problem with subforms, at least on 9.0.1FP2. But there has been a couple of changes on the behaviour from 8.5 to 9.0.

On one case, I have found that field type mismatches result in some unexpected problems (Blogged here: http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/more-xpages-error-fun....htm)

I suggest checking the types of those fields. For instance if you set a field as Date/Time but provide a String value, computeWithForm will not throw an error, instead the field will be empty. It's the same for formula errors.

To find the root cause, remove those fields one by one on a separate XPage-Form-Subform setting.